# strongly typed enum - `class` keyword optional?

Tags: c++11, c++14

In 'modern' C++ that suppports strongly typed enums: is the class keyword optional?

I saw code that defines enums like:

```
enum SomeEnum: unsigned int {
    VAL1 = 0,
    VAL2 = 1,
    // ...
};
```

Is this a different thing, a sloppyness of the compiler (VS 2015 (MSVC 19)) or is the `class` keyword implicit if the enum is strongly typed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `c++11` even normal enums (which still exist) can accept an underlying type specification. [See here.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum)

> enum-key attr(optional) identifier(optional) **enum-base(optional)(C++11)** { enumerator-list(optional) }

*Emphasis mine*

So it is a normal `enum` not a `enum class` but with a `enum-base` specification.

Answer (score 2):

The code in the question declares a normal unscoped enumeration, whose underlying type is however fixed. So it is different from `enum class` because it still does not introduce a scope for its enumerators.

Answer (score 1):

What you call "strongly typed enum" is really named [*scoped* enumerations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum#Scoped_enumerations), and for those the `class` or `struct` keyword is mandatory.

Using the "inheritance" syntax is not part of scoped enumerations, they can be used for normal [*unscoped* enumerations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum#Unscoped_enumeration) as well.